# Arctic underwater analogue?

Tags: jupiter, moons, saturn, habitat, ice

Just want to know if the underneath of the arctic ice sheet is a viable analogue for underwater habitation on the larger moons of the gas giants? (Galilean, large Saturnian)
I feel like it would be a perfect way to test tech for such an ambitious mission as a manned base beneath the surface of an ice moon.
Also, if you want to answer it, but don't feel pressured (haha science joke): do we have any current bases (subs too) that could be used as research vessels for such a test?
Cheers

Comment: Your comparison would be similar to having a Sunday picnic outside of Salt Lake City
 in order to prepare for a mission to Mars. For the Europa mission they are building a nuclear powered thermal drill to go through kilometers of ice. No place for humans.

Comment: It does seem that for advanced testing the pressure, currents, temperature gradients and remoteness of an ocean would test some aspects of an autonomous submarine vehicle that would be hard to reproduce all at the same time in a research lab pool, and there's all kinds of interesting things related to life going on at the bottom of the arctic and antarctic.